# iterate api response into html

Tags: node.js, express

How do I iterate API responses (50 products) into html list ? Results currently displayed automatically without styling. I just need to break all 50 products from results into seperate

tags.

index.js

```
<div class="column right" id="result">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function callAliExpressApi(index) {
          let url = '';
          if (index == 1) url = "/api/get-products";
          else if (index == 2)  url = "/api/get-hotproducts";
          //else if (index == 3)  url = "/api/get-hotproduct-download";
          else if (index == 3)  return;
          else if (index == 4)  url = "/api/get-categories";
          else if (index == 5)  url = "/api/get-featuredpromo-info";
          //else if (index == 6)  url = "/api/get-featuredpromo-products";
          else if (index == 6)  return;
          //else if (index == 7)  url = "/api/smart-match-products";
          else if (index == 7)  return;
    
          let result = '';
          $.get(url, function(data, status){
            for (i = 0 ; i < Object.keys(data).length ; i ++) {
              result = result + Object.keys(data)[i] + '=' + Object.values(data)[i] + '<br/>';
            }
            $("#result").html(result);
          });
        }
      </script>
```

sample.html

```
    <ul>
<li class="layer-slide gallery-book-slide">
    <div>
      <span class="gallery-book-list-img">
        <img src="{productimage}">
      </span>
      <div class="layer-region">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
          <div class="layer-inner">{productname}</div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <a href="{producturl}" target="_blank" class="gallery-book-product-text" title="">{producttitle}</a>
      <div class="gallery-book-author" title=""></div>
              <div class=" gallery-book-product-price">
        <div>
          <i>
            <span>￥</span>{productprice} </i>
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day,

To accomplish this you will need to inject html code using javascript. If your response is an array of 50 objects, you will need to iterate over every object and inject each object contents into html. To iterate you will need to use the map function.

```
[].map(value => {})
```

Please follow this guide on how to inject code into your page using javascript.
[More Information](https://labs.tadigital.com/index.php/2020/04/10/safe-ways-to-inject-html-through-javascript/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JS CreateElement Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            const response = [{name: "jack"}, {name: "slack"}, {name: "wack"}]
            response.map(value => {
            let div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = `<p>${value.name}</p>`;
            document.body.appendChild(div);
            })
           
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps to guide you in the right direction.